# Visual Studio (C#): Usar web.debug.config sem precisar publicar

Tags: c#, web.config

Eu gostaria de ter 2 arquivos de configuração na minha aplicação c#. Seriam eles: web.config e web.debug.config.

O objetivo disso é que eu possa colocar algumas configurações como acesso a banco de dados e algumas appsettings de acordo com o programador que estiver programando.

Ou seja, imagina que o programador A vai conectar no banco de dados com o usuario A e o programador B vai conectar no banco de dados com o usuário B.

Reparem que eu estou falando de conexão ao banco de dados e não permissão de acesso devido a x pessoa logada no meu sistema. É apenas para os programadores não mexerem na mesma base de dados.

Eu tentei fazer usando o web.debug.config, mas ele só é executado quando eu publico a aplicação. Aí isso não resolve, porque em produção, será apenas 1 usuário de conexão.

O que eu preciso é que cada programador possua a sua web.config.

Uma alternativa é colocarmos o web.config como ignore no git e assim cada um fica com o seu arquivo local. Mas, isso é ruim de administrar devido a outros campos que precisam ser editados no web.config.

Resumindo: É possível rodar o web.debug.config quando eu faço o F5 (Depuração)? Se não for possível, vocês tem alguma outra ideia?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você possa mover a conection string para um arquivo separado e adicionar apenas esse arquivo no git ignore.

**Web.Config**

```
 <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

**ConnectionStrings.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="name" connectionString="server=(local);database=db;user Id=usr;password=pass;timeout=0"></add>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Legal esse modelo. Não era a minha ideia inicial, mas foi bom conhecer que é possível separar parte do arquivo web.config. Obrigado por ajudar @lucas Silva.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você está usando o .Net "Full" framework, apesar de não estar especificado na pergunta. Neste caso, indicaria o uso do pacote/extensão slow cheetah.

A extensão adicionará recursos ao visual studio que facilitam o seu uso. O pacote nuget permitirá o uso de arquivos XML que provocam alterações à configuração original e é feito por ambiente.

Extensão: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms

Pacote nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/

Ao instalar as 2 bibliotecas acima o VS se encarregará automaticamente de todo o trabalho. E em seguida vc pode criar uma transformação para a connection string.

Encontrei este guia passo a passo, mas apesar estar em inglês, tem imagens de todos os passos: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/transform-config-using-slow-cheetah/